# SharePoint 2010 add a new search scope programmatically

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010

You can add a new search scope via powershell:
New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScope -SearchApplication "Search Service Application" -Name NewSearchScope -Description "New Search Test Scope" -DisplayInAdminUI 1–OwningSiteUrl http://servername/sites/

But does anyone know of sample code that shows how to do this via OM ? (using the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace rather than Microsoft.Office.Server.Search)

any pointers will be great

regards
Mo

*Update****
ignoring error handling / logging etc, is this a valid way of doing  this:

SPSite siteColl = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;

```
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceApplication spserviceapp = siteColl.SearchServiceInstance.Service.Applications["Search Service Application"];

        SearchServiceApplication searchserviceapp = (SearchServiceApplication)spserviceapp;

        ScopeInfo scopeInfo = new ScopeInfo(); 
        scopeInfo.Name = "Scope test1";
        scopeInfo.Description = "Scope test1";
        scopeInfo.DisplayInAdminUI = true;
        scopeInfo.CompilationType = ScopeCompilationType.AlwaysCompile;
        scopeInfo.CompilationState = ScopeCompilationState.NeedsCompile;            
        int statusCode = 0;
        int scopeId = searchserviceapp.AddScope(scopeInfo, out statusCode);
        if (scopeId > 0)
        {
            RuleInfo ruleInfo;
            ruleInfo = new RuleInfo(); 
            ruleInfo.FilterBehavior = ScopeRuleFilterBehavior.Include;
            ruleInfo.RuleType = ScopeRuleType.AllContent;
            int ruleId = searchserviceapp.AddRule(ruleInfo, scopeId);
        }
        searchserviceapp.Update(true);
```

---

rather then the ssp way of searchcontext?

SearchContext searchctx = null;
searchctx = SearchContext.GetContext(web.Site);
Scopes scopes = new Scopes(searchctx);
Scope currentScope = scopes.AllScopes.Create(
        "CurrentScopeName", string.Empty, new Uri(web.Site.Url), true,
        string.Format("{0}/Search/Pages/Results.aspx", web.Site.Url),
        ScopeCompilationType.AlwaysCompile);
currentScope.Update();
currentScope.Rules.CreateUrlRule(ScopeRuleFilterBehavior.Include,
        UrlScopeRuleType.Domain, web.Site.Url);
ScopeDisplayGroup group = scopes.GetDisplayGroup(new Uri(web.Url),
        "Search Dropdown");    group.Add(currentScope);
    group.Update();
scopes.StartCompilation();

```
scopes.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

`SearchContext` is marked as **obsolete** in SharePoint 2010 Server, so it is *not* the recommended way of doing it.

Also, see [this answer on SharePoint Overflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8601/sharepoint-2010-add-a-new-search-scope-programmatically/8604#8604).